# "Springiness" of rolled copper sheet

Tags: materials, solid-mechanics, material-science

When a copper sheet is rolled into cylinder, it tends to unroll itself. Is there any name for this?

Comment: It's called backlash. If the stuff jumps off the spool and escapes, it's usually called a bird's nest.

Answer (score 1):

Spiral torsion springs and constant-force springs behave in the same manner, although that's by design. A material's stiffness is what makes it want to resume its least stressed state. See Hooke's law.